# Why is JMS messaging client unable to start, with fedora-commons 3.8.1?

Tags: tomcat, jms, fedora-commons

I am trying to upgrade my fedora-commons and tomcat repository, so I run the .jar with the install.properties that was used for the old install of fedora-commons. It seems to start up fine without any issues but a few seconds after start up I get this error message in catalina.out:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start JMS Messaging Client, 5 attempts were made, each attempt resulted in a java.net.ConnectException. The messaging broker at tcp://localhost:61616 is not available
at com.yourmediashelf.fedora.client.messaging.MessagingClient$JMSBrokerConnector.connect(MessagingClient.java:389)
at com.yourmediashelf.fedora.client.messaging.MessagingClient$JMSBrokerConnector.run(MessagingClient.java:349)
```

I found an error message in the fedora.log, here it is:

```
ERROR 2015-06-10 11:41:57.966 [http-bio-8080-exec-23] (ContextLoader) Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.fcrepo.server.Server' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error while starting server
```

I am not able to get to the fedora/admin page but I can get to the tomcat page.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure the Fedora servlet is running? Can you get to the object search page at "http://yourserver.org:8080/fedora/objects/"?

Comment: No I cannot get to that page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I was copying over all my old files into the fedora directory before running the server startup that deploys the new fedora.war,fop.war...etc. So it was mixing outdated code with new code.

Comment: If that still does not resolve your problem double check to make sure you are not using OpenJDK. I've noticed OpenJDK causes the Fedora servlet to quietly fail even though the Tomcat server works quite well with it.

Comment: I am actually using OpenJDK i will try switching over to oracle to see it that helps, thanks for the suggestion